# Asymptotic equivalence of a real analytic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification, asymptotics

Let $f(x)$ be a real analytic function on the open set $(0,\infty)$. Also $f$ is non zero on $(0,\infty)$.

> My question: If $f(1)=1/2$ then as $x\to 1$, find an asymptotic equivalence of $\log f(x)$.

My try: Consider $g(x)=x\log(x/2)$.

Then we have $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\log f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log f(x)}{x\log (x/2)}$$
Now since $f$ has no zeros in $(0,\infty)$ so $\log f(x)$ is analytic on $(0,\infty)$. Now since $f(1)=1/2$ so we have $$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\log f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
So we have as $x\to 1$, $\log f(x)\sim g(x)$, where $g(x)=x\log(x/2)$.

Comment: Not fully versed in this subject,  but wouldn't the simple constant function $g(x)=-\log 2$ work?

Comment: @Alan Is my choice not correct?

Comment: @Mary There is no single right answer. Yours is correct, but Alan's is much simpler.

Comment: @Mary Note in general that if $f$ has a limit not $0$ or $\pm \infty$, then $f\sim g$ simply means $\lim f=\lim g$.